# Resolve conversion from integer to smaller pointer warning without union

Tags: c, pointers

When I make this assignment:

```
const uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *)(uint64_t address);
```

i get

```
conversion from integer to smaller pointer warning
```

So i want to save  a uint8_t pointer from a uint64_t integer. I can't modify neither types.

LE:so the entire code looks smth like this

```
typedef token{
const uint8_t *pTr;
}token;

typedef key{
uint64_t srcAddress;
}key;
```

in a function that gets pointers to the both structures as input, i want to do:

```
token->pTr = key->srcAddress
```

Comment: Are you on a 32-bit system, where pointers are 32 bits?

Comment: To silence the warning, you probably need *two* casts: First to `uintptr_t` and then to the actual pointer: `const uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *) (uintptr_t) value;`

Comment: is a 64bit system. how safe is the uintptr_t cast for  a security grade project?

Comment: What's the output of `printf("%zu\n", sizeof(uint8_t *));`

Comment: Also, is this an embedded system, where certain memory structures reside at fixed addresses?

Comment: Then are you *building* in 32-bit mode (using e.g. the `-m32` option for GCC)?

Comment: What is `const uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *)(uint64_t address);` even supposed to mean? Is this the real code?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a uint64_t variable in your program, the right way to do this is:

```
uint64_t address = ...;
const uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *)(&address);
```

It is also a good idea to keep in mind the endianness of the cpu.

Comment: `const uint8_t *p = (uint8_t *) (uintptr_t) value; ` is actually optimized by compiler to your suggestion. thx mate

Comment: I think in OP's original, the `address` variable was a numeric address to be converted to a `uint8_t *` in `p`. But you currently have `p` pointing to the `address` variable itself.

Comment: @IanAbbott Agreed.  The code posted in this answer does not do anything at all like what the code posted in the question seems to intend.  This answer takes the *address* of the `address` variable, whereas the code in the question takes the *value* held by the `address` variable.  This answer looks flat-out wrong.

Comment: @AndrewHenle i updated the code. for me also is a little bit strange that it works as intended

Comment: @ValValli after the LE, maybe it works because of some logic mismatch?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to get the address value to an array with 8 8-bit elements? If you want to do so, you can do like this:

```
uint64_t address;
uint8_t* p;
p = &address;
```

and then you can use p as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Here is get memory address like variable and assign to other pointer.

```
    uint8_t *a = (uint8_t*)malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
    uint64_t address = (uint64_t)a;
    uint8_t *b = (uint8_t*)address;
    *b = 10;
    printf("%d\n", *a);
```

Outputs `10` so `a == b` and have address in memory `address`.